# Hooking subprocess logs into main log output in Docker

Tags: docker, sungridengine

I'm running SGE (Sun Grid Engine) in a Docker container in order to replicate our live SGE cluster. If you haven't run across it, SGE is basically a program that runs other programs (while managing resources across a cluster - i.e. a grid scheduler). That is of course in conflict with the docker "one process per container" philosophy (and if you follow down this path of reasoning far enough you'll think "why use a grid scheduler rather than just sticking docker containers on Swarm or Kubernetes or something", and you'd be right, only I can't change our whole scheduling infrastructure to fix this problem, sadly).

So, I'm trying to get the logs out of those programs run by SGE and into the general docker log. The qsub command (which submits jobs to the SGE queue for running) takes arguments which allow you to specify the location of STDOUT and STDERR.

The best attempt that I have managed so far is to start the two main processes (sge_execd and sge_qmaster) via a script which never terminates (good old tail -f /dev/null), and then do something like the following:

```
qsub -o /proc/1/fd/1 -e /proc/1/fd/2 my_script
```

This horrific hack is hooking into the file descriptors of process 1 (i.e. our tail -f-ing, sge-invoking process), which happens to have its STDOUT and STDERR connected to the docker logs, as you might expect.

This feels pretty nasty, though. Can someone suggest a better way of achieving this?